# Microsoft Test Manager Not executed is shown in the test run

Tags: coded-ui-tests, mtm

I try to execute a test case automated. But just after pressing run test, the test has a Not Executed status. It displays Pending for a while, then Active. but nothing can be seen in the test controller side that the test runs.

Then the Not Executed with no logs is dipslayed.
Regards

Comment: did you associate automation with the test, or are you trying to run the previous recorded steps from a test case? what kind of an application are you testing? windows forms, wpf, store app, web?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same scenario & eventually found that the Test Client machine was out of hard disk space. Clearing some space enabled me to rerun my tests